# Merge and update primary key

Tags: mysql, merge

I looked, but didn't find a solution to what seems like a simple problem.

I have many tables with identical structure and want to merge them. The only problem is that they all have an id field as the primary key. There would be a lot of duplicates in the primary key. It doesn't matter what the id ends up being. How can I merge all the tables so I don't loose any data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in the new table and omit it from the list of values:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, col1 …, col2 …, …);

INSERT
INTO    new_table (col1, col2, …)
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM    old_table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM    old_table_2
UNION ALL
…
```

Comment: Yes, very simple code - thanks. I have a slightly different requirement, though. I need to add an identifier to the set of rows from each old table. So the new_table has a new column, in which the name of the old table goes. Can this be done in one operation?

Answer (score 1):

In the destination table use an auto incrementing field as the primary key. Then copy all the columns from the other tables *except the primary key* into your new table.

```
INSERT new_table (col1, col2 , col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM old_table
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I figured it was something simple like that.

Comment: Is there a way to do more than one table at a time?

Comment: @BrNathan: Yes you can use UNION ALL, as Quassnoi already posted.