# Merge tables and assign new primary keys where necessary

Tags: mysql, merge

I am merging two tables that have the potential to have the same primary key (id) which will produce a Duplicate entry error.
I am OK with having new primary keys generated for the inserted data or even the existing data, so if the example databases are:

```
table_a
Id | Name
----------
1  | Jack
----------
2  | Jill
----------
3  | John
----------

table_b
Id | Name
----------
1  | Jim
----------
2  | Jenny
----------
3  | Joy
----------
```

And the Import script is `INSERT INTO table_a SELECT * FROM table_b;`

How do I get the script to assign new ids when they are detected as duplicate?

I realise I could do `INSERT INTO table_a (name) SELECT name FROM table_b`, in a similar way to that described on [Merge and update primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526972/merge-and-update-primary-key), but I have nearly 100 tables of different structures that I need to merge and would prefer to be able to use `SELECT *` and assign new ids.

Comment: you should use an autoincrement for id and the add only the name not present in your destination table  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another column which specifies the type of the result table.
For example in the `table_a` (Result table) you should add a column named `type` of `INT` type (Or of `BIT` type here), then you need to specify for example `0` means the data for `table_a` and `1` means the data for `table_b`.
So in the result table (`table_a`) you have following fields:

- Id (INT - P.K. AutoIncrement)
- Type (INT)
- TableRelatedId (INT as you already defined)
- Name (VARCHAR as you already defined)

Before inserting record you first update the table 'table_a' by type 0

`UPDATE table_b SET type = 0`

and then merge `table_b` with `table_a` by following `INSERT`:

`INSERT table_a([Type], TableRelatedId, Name) SELECT 1, Id, Name FROM table_b`

Comment: Although I was after a solution that used SELECT *, which I now think isn’t possible, this answer pointed me in the right direction and I based my working code on this.